# How to Count UNCOMMITTED ISOLATION LEVEL in mysql with gorm?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying count order by dirty read (READ UNCOMMITTED) mysql with gorm. But gorm Raw Scan isn't correct working.
I have 3 orders in table orders in database and 1 orders created without commit / rollback in transaction. Count result should be 4 instead of 3 in raw scan result.

```
func (o *OrderRepositoryAdapter) CountOrderByAttendeeIDAndEventID(ctx context.Context, attendeeID uint, eventID uint) (uint, error) {
    var count int64
    query := "START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE orders.attendee_id = 1 AND orders.event_id = 1"
    tx := o.db.Begin()
    if err := tx.WithContext(ctx).Raw(query).Scan(&count).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return 0, err
    }
    return uint(count), nil
}
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? I'm assuming your trying to implement a event limit of attendees. There's possibly a better way if you can define your constraints.

Comment: You can't change the transaction isolation of the current transaction after you start that transaction. Changing the isolation level only applies to transactions started subsequently in the same session.

Comment: Also, using READ UNCOMMITTED is in my opinion never a good solution. It leads to phantom reads.